# Postgres permission problem on docker desktop, windows

Tags: postgresql, docker

I know there are a lot of information on this topic, but for some reasons, it doesn't help. Maybe because it's Windows. I kinda understand how exactly it should work on linux and it works, but my linux machine freezes each time I run the whole project, probably due to lack of RAM or other issues connected with that particular machine. And my main machine uses Windows with docker desktop.

Tried to delete folder data, do `sudo chown -R 999:999 ./data`, change db user, move to different folder, sync with repo, clone again from zero.. It just doesn't work.

Getting

```
2023-03-11 10:38:49 chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
```

each time I try to run my docker image with postgres.
Here is a fragment of compose with postgres:

```
postgres:
  image: postgis/postgis:15-master
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: directus
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepasswd
  POSTGRES_DB: directus
healthcheck:
  test: pg_isready -U miniflux
  interval: 10s
  start_period: 30s
```

What I have now:

- I use docker desktop with WSL integration (ubuntu LTS 22.04) on Windows
- I have all perms on data folder on my main WSL user, as well as ownership
- Everything is obviously on ntfs volume cause windows doesn't support anything else (heard that it can't work on some filesystems)
- I run compose using `sudo docker compose up`. Can't do it without sudo, getting errors (like entrypoint default is invalid)
- There is at least one member in my team who managed make it work on Windows, but he can't explain how (like, he have no clue, LOL)
- Everyone I talked to in my team said that there was error like this, but most of them just moved to linux

Comment: Have you tried using a named Docker volume instead of the dir mount?

Comment: You gave me an idea, I'll try it and write about results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seems like I'm really stupid... I shoot my leg just by trying to run it on NTFS.

It didn't work cause it was on windows ntfs system, and you can't change permission on this fs, only on ext4. Actually, you can, but it's windows permissions, this is completely different thing. And there is ext4 filesystem in WSL, in it's standart folders in / . Everything in /mnt/... are ntfs Windows volumes, just mounted by WSL. DBs and postgres especially can't work on NTFS due to permission problem.

When I was trying to change permissions it didn't work, but I didn't get any error. Only now I noticed that permissions stayed the same after executing chown.